# how to build an UI for asp.net membership using mvc

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, membership-provider

I'm using the out of the box asp.net membership provider to manage my login on my site. I'm wanting to build a user interface in my app so that I can manage the user's permissions / other. Would it be best to build my own membership provider or keep with using this? Are their any 'good' references to get me started? 
thanks,

Comment: The whole point of Membership is to provide a standardized UI, so you don't need a new UI for each kind of Membership provider.  So no, you should not create a custom provider, at least not just for managing users.

Comment: thanks, so when you say standardized UI are you speaking of the out of the box website admin tool? What I'm wanting to do is create a section  in my website that when admins are logged in they can manage user permission / other right in the site.

Comment: I'm sorry, I meant standardized API, not ui.  But yes, also a standard administration UI.  MS doesn't provide one that you can access externally, unfortunately.  The administration tool can only be run in cassini on a computer with Visual Studio installed on it.  Yes, I know exactly what you want to do, but I was referring to your question about creating a custom provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Troy Goode created a nice NuGet Package that should help get you started:

"The starter kit provides the Asp.Net MVC controllers, models, and views needed to administer users & roles. This package contains classes needed by the MvcMembership.Mvc package to provide a testable interface to ASP.Net's MembershipProvider and RoleProvider features."

http://nuget.org/packages/MvcMembership

Answer (score 0):

Beating my drum, but: http://websitemanager.codeplex.com/ :)

HTH.